# Check constraint when using @Enumerated? Spring Boot - JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

If I have the following entity and enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MyEnum myEnum;
}
```

Is there a way to have a constraint created on the database without me having to actually write the constraint in SQL?

This is what i want to avoid:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(60) CHECK (myEnum IN ('VALUE_1', 'VALUE_2')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about the `columnDefinition` attribute

> This property allows you to use the Data Definition Language (DDL) to define the structure of a column. Then, we can generate the table from the entity using the JPA Tool with this definition.

[source](https://huongdanjava.com/learn-about-column-annotation-in-jpa.html)

and about JPA

> (JPA)... greatly simplifies Java persistence and provides an object-relational mapping approach that lets you declaratively define how to map Java objects to relational database tables in a standard, portable way that works

[2]

From these citings, I think:

- using the `columnDefinition` attribute is the best practice especially since JPA is the tool you are using to persist your DB
- No, there is no other way better way to create the constraints in the database

---

[2]: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm#:~:text=The%20Java%20Persistence%20API%20(JPA,standard%2C%20portable%20way%20that%20works